# what is the reason that "would " here to be used?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> *"Australopithecus afarensis had much longer arms and larger hands, which **would have been** useful for climbing trees"*

(Note: Australopithecus aferencis was the early type of human beings)

again "would" involved sentence and again I'm facing a high dose of perplexity   -  What kind of sense an author wanted to give to the sentence by using "would have" construction?  I mean, couldn't we replace the *"would have been"*  with  *"was"* here?

Comment: It forms a conjecture about a past event. It means something like "... which [scientists believe] would have been useful ..."

Comment: you mean an author thinks that the longer arms together with larger hands would have probably be useful for climbing trees? then could we replace it with "was" to suggest certainty ?

Comment: No, because it's a *conjecture*, not an absolute statement of fact. The truth is, they *would* have been useful, but to say that they *were* useful would imply a lot of other specific evidence that the longer limbs did in fact get used in this manner. Even then, scientists would admit the possibility of error in their hypothesis. This is one of the differences between a scientist and, say, a politician.

Comment: Robusto is correct. The writer is making an educated assumption (guess) about how having longer arms and larger hands may have helped *Australopithecus afarensis* to thrive. No one actually knows, since there is no written record. So you are also correct that if we replace "would have been" with "was," it would suggest a certainty that we don't possess.

Comment: Clouds don't run (and that's a certainty).

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience after 16 days :( but revising the question I've just noticed that I completely forgot to ask the question I had intended to ask regarding the context - What if we simply use "would be" rather than "would have been" ? How does it affect the meaning?

Answer (score 1):

Would can be the proper word depending on the context. Did Australopithecus afarensis climb trees? If not, then would is being correctly used in the excerpt. Another possibility is that we don't know whether Australopithecus afarensis climbed trees. In this case, would also works as signifying possibility. Otherwise, was would be the correct answer ;).